# Running into an issue: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program in Python to calculate compound interest. I'm using the general formula A=P(1+r/n)^nt

When I run the program I get the error "int object is not callable"

```
    import sys

    P = int (sys.argv[1])
    R = int (sys.argv[2])
    N = int (sys.argv[3])
    T = int (sys.argv[4])
    A = P(1 + (R / N)) ** (N*T)

    print(round(A, 1))
```

That's the code. The idea is to substitute random inputs for the variables and have Python spit back a number rounded to the tenths decimal. Any ideas? I'm basically in day 2 of Python.

Comment: Typo: change to `A = P * (1 + (R / N)) ** (N*T)`

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't multiply P with the rest, but rather try to call `P(...)` just put an asterix `*` between P and the bracket. There are no implicit multiplications in programming